# cargo build-bpf command not working for solana

Tags: rust, blockchain, smartcontracts, rust-cargo, solana

I'm getting this error after I execute the command `cargo build-bpf` to build the program for Solana on Windows 10.

```
info: uninstalling toolchain 'bpf'
info: toolchain 'bpf' uninstalled 
error: no such command: `+bpf`

        Cargo does not handle `+toolchain` directives.
        Did you mean to invoke `cargo` through `rustup` instead?`
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ever find a solution to this?